# Get Twitter Members list

Tags: ios, objective-c, twitter, sttwitter

I m trying to get the list of the members of the group iOS Developers from Twitter Groups.

I m using STTwitterAPI. I used it to get the news feed of specific account, and it works so fine.
But when i tried to get the list of the members by using the functions (getListsMembersForSlug or getListsMembersForListID) it didn't work, I get the following error :

> Description : Error Domain=STHTTPRequest Code=404 "The operation
>   couldn’t be completed. (STHTTPRequest error 404.)"

The code I m using is :

```
STTwitterAPI *twitter = [STTwitterAPI twitterAPIAppOnlyWithConsumerKey:@"MyConsumerKey" consumerSecret:@"MyconsumerSecret"];

[twitter verifyCredentialsWithSuccessBlock:^(NSString *bearerToken) {

    NSNumber *t = [NSNumber numberWithInt:1];

    [twitter getListsMembersForSlug:@"iOS Developers" ownerScreenName:@"Gadget_Ry" orOwnerID:nil cursor:false includeEntities:false skipStatus:t successBlock:^(NSArray *users, NSString *previousCursor, NSString *nextCursor) {
        NSLog(@"Ok");
        } errorBlock:^(NSError *error) {
            NSLog(@"NOk");
    }];

} errorBlock:^(NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"%@", error.debugDescription);
}];
```

Can anyone help me please? Any suggestions! Tutorials! I'll be grateful :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`iOS Developers` is not a slug.

`iOS-Developers` is a slug.

:-)

Comment: It does totally provide an answer to the question. The API requires a slug and works like a charm when provided a slug.

Comment: I agree that my response was a bit cryptic :) in fact, and for future reference for STTwitter users, reading errors can help a lot. In this case, the error was: "You must specify either a list ID or a slug and owner.".